# Написал парсер, видимо проблема с кодировкой когда сохраняется в csv файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, utf-8

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def save_file(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['Название объявления', 'Ссылка', 'Цена', 'Гео'])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item['title'], item['link'], item['price'], item['geo']])**
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А в чем вопрос/проблема?

Comment: На изображении проблема, после импорта в csv вот такая вот фигня

Comment: Английские буквы есть, а вместо русских вот это

Comment: @StepanBalakirev, не вижу изображение в вопросе :) Подправил картинку. Кст, на стек картинки можно вставлять из буфера обмена, просто через `Ctrl + V`, что очень удобно :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `open(path, 'w', newline='')` не хватает указания кодировки, а без нее будет использоваться системная кодировка, попробуйте явно указывать кодировку `utf-8`:

```
with open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as file:
```

Comment: Помогло, открыл через блокнот csv файл - все супер. А через excel тоже самое, видимо дело в нем...

Comment: спасибо большое !

Comment: @StepanBalakirev, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: А для экселя попробуйте сохранить `csv` с кодировкой `encoding='cp1251'`